# Can nickel(IV) be stabilised in water using appropriate ligands?

Tags: coordination-compounds, theoretical-chemistry, stability

Platinum(IV) is perfectly stable in water as its hexachlorido complex, and so is palladium(IV). However, nickel(IV) is not stable in water even in its hexafluorido complex- the exchange-inertness of hexafluoridonickelate(IV) (which is low-spin despite the strong pi-donor property of fluoride; nickel(IV) is "just too high in oxidation state" to admit a high-spin configuration) does not reduce the strong oxidising ability of the central nickel(IV).

My initial guess was that hexaamminenickel(IV) and/or hexacyanidonickelate(IV) would be stable in water, since the otherwise hydrolytically unstable cobalt(III) can be stabilised that way, but I could not find any information about the hydrolytic stability of either ion. So I'm asking it here, just in case stronger sigma-donors than ammonia/cyanide are necessary.

Comment: P.S. Hexafluoridocobaltate(III) is high-spin, although that fact would likely not be relevant here.

Comment: related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ni(IV)_organometallic_complex

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0277538711005195

Comment: Seems dimethylglyoxime can stabilise it enough for strongly basic solution https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022072864800826

Answer (score 3):

Nickel may be oxidized from nickel(II) to nickel(IV) with diacetylpyridine dioxime ligands[1] and also in polyniobate complexes[2], in the latter case using hypobromite as the oxidizing agent. The latter reference also notes a Ni(IV) molybdate complex.

**References**

1.
Everett I. Baucom and Russell S. Drago. "Nickel(II) and nickel(IV) complexes of 2,6-diacetylpyridine dioxime". *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* 1971, **93**, 24, 6469–6475.
https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00753a022

2.
Charles M. Flynn Jr. and Galen D. Stucky."Heteropolyniobate complexes of manganese(IV) and nickel(IV)".
*Inorg. Chem.* 1969, **8**, 2, 332–334.
https://doi.org/10.1021/ic50072a029